# Spring MVC autobinding can not access map data in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to java and was trying to test thymeleaf in springboot.
with code like the first controller I can access the data in a map through thymeleaf

but can not access the data in a map by the second controller.
why declaring map like 2nd method can't work?
can someone help me? thx

```
public class ViewController {
public String index(Map<String, Object> map) {
    map.put("hello","Bonjour");
    map.put("Users", Arrays.asList("Ken","Yu","JY"));       
    return "index";
}
```

### }

```
public class ViewController {
public String index() {
    Map<String, Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("hello","Bonjour");
    map.put("Users", Arrays.asList("Ken","Yu","JY"));   
    return "index";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Springboot follows the Model View Controller (MVC) architecture . Simply put Models are used to supply attributes to the view to be rendered.Here you are using thyme-leaf as the view renderer while the model is fed into the thyme-leaf template.Model, ModelMap, and ModelAndView are used to define a model in a Spring MVC application.Spring boot automatically takes care of binding the view and the model together.

As such springboot `@RequestMapping` handler method expects the method argument for model as :

> java.util.Map / org.springframework.ui.Model /
>   org.springframework.ui.ModelMap for enriching the implicit model that
>   is exposed to the web view.

[Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

So if you provide a map as a method parameter it is automatically bound the view.In your second case that it not happening automatically .That is the reason second method does not work.Example using ModelAndView :

```
@GetMapping("/goToIndexPage")
public ModelAndView methodWithModelAndViewReturn() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
    modelAndView.addObject("message", "Hello");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation. Now I know it is the Spring MVC autobinding at issue. Changed the title to better reflect my problem.

Comment: @Ken Happy to be of help.